# Probability of tie vote

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are two candidates Alpha and Beta running for a champion in a show. A,B,C are three individuals and each has 50 votes which could be distributed to two candidates based on his will,say A likes candidate Alpha more so he splits 50 into 27 and 23 for Alpha and Beta. He could also give all the votes to the same candidate.

D is a group of 100 people, with each individual in this group has one vote per person. Each one can vote either Alpha or Beta, but he cannot give up the vote.

Question is, what is the probability of total votes from A,B,C,D adding up draws a tie between Alpha and Beta?

My way of calculating is ${250 \choose 125} * (0.5^{125})(0.5^{125}).$ Does it look right?

Comment: Are you sure that's the question? You gave no information about the probabilities of preferences of the voters. Is each voter effectively "flipping a coin" to decide who to give each of their votes for?

Comment: It is like flip a coin, the preference for each person is 0.5, 0.5 because two candidates are equally likely eligible for champion.

Comment: Could you provide more context? (Just curious: Is it related to RoC, a recent hip-hop competition programme aired by iQiYi?)

Comment: Does each of A, B, C in effect toss 50 fair coins? Then its $P(X=125),$ with $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(250, .5),$ and in R the statement `dbinom(125, 250, .5)` returns  0.05041221.$ To get a numerical answer, your computation has to be done carefully to avoid overflow and/or underflow.

Comment: I see, so there is no need to consider how many combinations would A, B, C,D add up to 125 given A,B,C within range(0,50) and D within range(0,100)?